# Google Drive Error on Synching

Tags: windows-7, google-api, synchronization

I have had issues with Google Drive Synch'n on a windows 7 32 bit box.

I don't want to disconnect and re-synch everything. I asked Google for help (Google Apps Business) and they basically aren't helping... they say upload things using the UI (what happened to sync?)!!

Anyway, I thought somebody would have some insight having dealt with the Google Drive API.

I get this in the synch_log file...

```
2013-04-26 10:06:21,151 INFO 2252:Fetcher         common.fetcher:303 Existing batch of work complete. Pending change count = 1694
2013-04-26 10:06:22,151 ERROR 2252:Fetcher         common.fetcher:314 BLACKLIST: 
Request: FSChange('Direction.UPLOAD', 'Action.CREATE', 'ino: 866379978315695464', u'path: \\\\?\\C:\\Users\\robert\\Google Drive\\GunCycle\\Auctions\\Auction1\\Garand', u'name: Springfield M1A 048123', 'parent ino: 10738551836488547027', 'folder?: True', 'modified: 1366897690', 'generator_module: 1', 'is_cancelled: False', 'CID: 368'), Failure: InternalError: long too big to convert, recovery plan: 4, recovery targets: set([]) 
Request: FSChange('Direction.UPLOAD', 'Action.CREATE', 'ino: 90353467524417019', u'path: \\\\?\\C:\\Users\\robert\\Google Drive\\GunCycle\\Auctions\\Auction1\\Garand', u'name: Springfield M1 1637780', 'parent ino: 10738551836488547027', 'folder?: True', 'modified: 1366980351', 'generator_module: 1', 'is_cancelled: False', 'CID: 1410'), Failure: InternalError: long too big to convert, recovery plan: 4, recovery targets: set([])
```

This repeats many times with the 'Pending Change Count' never changing.

```
2013-04-26 09:45:51,644 INFO 7248:Fetcher         common.fetcher:303 Existing batch of work complete. Pending change count = 1694
2013-04-26 09:45:52,430 WARNING 7656:InternalScheduler common.push.tango.system_resources:110 TICL_LOG: Incoming message has bad token: "\n\006\n\004\010\003\020\001\022\022\tt@\373x\227\233\257\201\021%L\372aW?H9\032\007\010\203\022\020\003\030\013", "\n\006\n\004\010\003\020\001\022\022\t_\006\334\310\013\235\312\224\021\265I\350\326\250\000\276\265\032\007\010\203\022\020\003\030\013"
2013-04-26 09:45:52,654 INFO 7248:Fetcher         logging:1600 Crash reporting throttled. Ignoring report.
2013-04-26 09:45:52,654 ERROR 7248:Fetcher         logging:1575 Ignoring non-fatal error: OverflowError: long too big to convert, Traceback:
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.fetcher", line 196, in _Process
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.fetcher", line 354, in _GetNextChange
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.persistence_sqlite", line 132, in Wrapper
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.fetcher", line 401, in _GetNextChangeFromQueue
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.fetcher", line 415, in _BlacklistChangeAndReportException
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.blacklist", line 228, in Blacklist
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.persistence_sqlite", line 132, in Wrapper
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.blacklist", line 182, in _CreateBlacklistInfo
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.delivery", line 427, in GetPath
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.snapshot_persistence_interface", line 558, in GetLocalPath
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.snapshot_sqlite", line 350, in _GetLocalEntryFilename
  File "P:\p\agents\hpal4.eem\recipes\253073741\base\b\drb\googleclient\apps\webdrive_sync\windows\build\pyi.win32\main\outPYZ1.pyz/common.sqlite_operations", line 117, in Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I basically just disconnect the account, moved the Google Drive local folder and then re-started sync.

Once that was done, I compared the two folders using SyncBack SE and then moved the updated and yet un-sync'd items to the new Google Drive folder. Then, trashed the old one.

Major pain and Google is "working on a fix" but "has no time estimate".

So, I assume this will happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This was finally resolved with the new release of Google Drive.